# ペネトレーションテストツールTails,Kali,Qubesの違いを教えてください。

Tags: linux

これらの違いを聞かれたのですがどれも違いがないと思いました。
テストに際してどのディストリビュートがいいのかわからないので教えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

どれもセキュリティに重点を置いたディストリビューションではありますが、ペネトレーションテスト用と言えるのは Kali Linux だけではないでしょうか？

検索して調べた程度なので実際にはそのような使い方もされているのかもしれませんが・・・。

### Kali Linux

攻撃・テストツールや解析ツールを備えたディストリビューション。Wireshark、Metasploit、Burpsuite、Aircrack-ng といった有名どころをはじめ、様々なパッケージが用意されているようです。

- [Kali Linuxとは? | Kali Linux](http://ja.docs.kali.org/introduction-ja/kali-linux%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF)
- [攻撃者の心理 Kali Linux紹介 1 | ITオフィスサポートとシステム開発|システムガーディアン](http://sys-guard.com/post-2896/)
- [Kali Linux Metapackages | Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-metapackages/)
- [Kali Linux - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux)

### Tails

匿名性に重点を置いたディストリビューション、というかライブOS。Tor を使うことでインターネット上での匿名性を確保するほか、暗号化ファイルシステムなどを標準装備している。

- [Tails v1.0 : 通信の安全性に優れた Linux ディストリビューション - Linux.com](https://jp.linux.com/news/linuxcom-exclusive/416720-lco20140512)
- [Tails (operating system) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tails_(operating_system))

### Qubes OS

Xen による仮想化でアプリケーションを分離し、セキュリティを高めるディストリビューション。ネットワークやストレージへのアクセスも専用のVMを通すことで、ハードウェアへ直接アクセスすることを防ぐ。各VMで動作するアプリケーションをシームレスに操作するための仕組みなども用意されているようです。

- [Introduction to Qubes OS(ja) // Speaker Deck](https://speakerdeck.com/ntddk/introduction-to-qubes-os-ja)
- [Qubes OS - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubes_OS)

Answer (score 4):

- Tails
  匿名性に特化したLinuxのディストリビュート
  例えば、DoS攻撃を回避するための訓練に利用できます。攻撃と防御に別れそれぞれ指揮を取りながらサーバーを守る体制を確立します。
- Kali
  侵入に特化したLinuxのディストリビュート
  例えば、Wi-fiのセキュリティレベルの確認や自己サーバのセキュリティレベルの確認などが行えます。
- Qubes
  ウイルスに対して特化したLinuxのディストリビュート
  アンチウイルスソフト開発者が、ウイルスの動作を確認するために使います。

サーバー管理者であれば、安全性を確保するためにTailsとKaliでのテストが必要になります
施設を管理も任されているのならKaliによるWifiのセキュリティチェックも必要でしょう
Qubesは、ワクチンソフトを開発する場合に必要になると思います。